# discord bot login timeout using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have created a bot with the following code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
   intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages],
   restRequestTimeout: 120 * 1000,
});

const TOKEN = "MTA0xxxxx";

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login(TOKEN).catch(console.error);
```

and then when I run `node index.js`, I got

```
RequestAbortedError [AbortError]: Request aborted
    at abort (/Users/chenxu/discord_bot/node_modules/undici/lib/api/abort-signal.js:10:18)
    at self.<computed> (/Users/chenxu/discord_bot/node_modules/undici/lib/api/abort-signal.js:29:5)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:645:20)
    at AbortSignal.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:587:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:292:10)
    at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:322:5)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/chenxu/discord_bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:515:73)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_ABORTED'
}
```

Can anyone help me on this, thanks.

Comment: first things first, login returns a promise: public login(token?: string): Promise<string>;

Answer (score 0):

It might be a VPN, or network connection issue, I put my code into replit.com, everything starts to work.